# Why isn't my link being styled?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have an external CSS and one of my ID's isn't working.

```css
#head {
  font-family: baskerville old face, serif;
  font-size: 35pt;
  margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 45px #FF1493, 0px 0px 65px #C71585;
}
#head a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="head"> <a href="fullaccess.html">Factbox</a> 
</p>
```

The head ID is working but the head a isn't, and I don't know why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with: #head a:link?

Comment: Do you have other CSS that might be taking precedence over this CSS?

Comment: Your code snippet is working fine in chrome, black text no underline, checked in developer tools and styles where applied.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had a comment tag that I didn't format correctly under the #head ID and above the #head a ID.